# Connecting an OpenWrt router to a “dumb” modem provided to me by my ISP

Tags: networking, router, bridge, openwrt

My ISP game me a device that offers hardly any configuration possibilities.
The Wi-Fi is also bad. So I decided to buy another router and flashed it with OpenWrt.

Unfortunately, I cannot replace my modem because otherwise I am not able to connect to the internet.

What I achieved so far:

[image]

OpenWrt Router is running a DHCP Server and gives out IP addresses within `192.168.1.1/24`. This works well for Device 0, Device 1, as well as Device X. Every device can connect to the internet and ping each other.

When I connect Device 2 to my modem it also receives an IP within `192.168.1/24`. It looks like that it does not found any route to my OpenWrt router, or at least it does not know that it could use the IP Address `192.168.0.2` as a gateway to the other subnet. Please remember there is not much I can configure within my modem's settings.

Do you have any ideas on how to make it possible that Device 2 can connect to the internet as well as to connect to any other device? Should I put the OpenWrt into the same subnet? How would I configure the DHCP Server to use OpenWrt as Gateway/DNS for every device to be able to use the OpenWrt adblock feature, which is using a special local DNS as far as I understood? Or is it possible to use a bridge on OpenWrt Router side?

Update:

1. I want to connect Device2 to my Modem since it is basically a Router and it has open ethernet Ports. I do not want to buy an additional Switch as long as I  don't need to.
2. My Modem is something propietary from Vodafone Germany for Cable (Docis 3.1) Access: [image]
3. My OpenWRT Router is a TP-LINK Archer C7

Comment: As a heads up, this question belongs on SuperUser, because it relates to home networking.

Comment: I don't think your "modem" is dumb, since it's acting as a modem, router, wi-fi access point and probably switch (if it has more than one Ethernet ports); you simply don't have administrative access to it and can't change its config, but this does not mean it's "dumb" as you think.

Comment: Why the heck are you attempting to connect Device 2 directly to your modem? What do you think you get from doing that? That device should just be connected directly to the router.

Comment: What are you planning on using dd-wrt for?  Also, can you clarify if you have connected a land or wan interface from the dd-wrt box to the modem - and what your thinking behind that decision was. (I'm trying to work out whether you actually want to use the dd-wrt box as a router or just make it into an AP)

Comment: @davidgo the link between the modem/router and the WRT box is labeled "WAN", and the rest of the problem indicates that it's behind a NAT. As far as why use OpenWRT - its a good system to use for a router, and one of the main goals of this project was to get a better WiFi device - that's easy to do if you can choose which radio to install, and OpenWRT supports a wide range of radio chipsets. Of course, this is mild conjecture - but those components of this network seem well-planned.

Comment: Though we really do need to know more about this modem/router. A model number would be nice.

Comment: @spooler you are assuming facts not in evidence. If the wan of the dd-wrt box was connected to the modem that leaves device 2's IP address unexplained (but your interpretation is supported - weekly - by the diagram).  Similarly "using a bridge" may depict a willingness to give up some dd-wrt functionality.   Until we know why device 2 is not behind dd-wrt and can deduce the logic behind how they want it to work - which the cabling will hint at - I don't think we can accurately answer.

Comment: @davidgo Small clarification to avoid confusion, but the original poster is talking about OpenWrt and not DD-WRT.

Comment: My OpenWRT Router has only four Ethernet ports and I do not want to add any additional switch to my setup as long as I am having unused ethernet Ports. Thus, I guess I should have called the modem also just router.

Comment: If that's the case, you're wanting to extend the port count of that modem/router. I don't see any detail in this case that would suggest using the OpenWRT box as a bridge instead of a router would degrade some desired functionality - this would effectively place both devices on the same L2/3 domain, which would solve your port count issues and make every port go to the same network. This is option #1 in my answer.

Comment: @caiuspb If you confirm that, I can detail how that could be accomplished.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that. My open question is if I need to configure my openwrt as a bridge? and I would like to use it also for dhcp server, dns and adblock if possible. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things going on here. I'll summarize.

That "modem" is much more than a modem. It's a router, DHCP server, DNS server, gateway (to the modem) and an L2 bridge (switch). We'll call that network device R0.

The OpenWRT device (we'll call it R1) is also all of those things, with the exception that its gateway route points to R0's private L2/3 domain (192.168.0.0/24). You created 192.168.1.0/24 yourself outside of the scope of R0, and did not configure R0 to route to that subnet. R1 is also configured as a NAT gateway for that subnet, which further obscures it from 0.0. The configuration you've rendered has effectively isolated 1.0 from 0.0, as if 0.0 is a public subnet, and 1.0 is a private subnet. 1.0 can get to resources on 0.0, and can use 0.1 as a gateway to the internet, but 0.0 cannot get to 1.0 without configuring the R1 NAT to do so (via port forwarding or similar). This is referred to as a "double NAT".

This brings up a question: Why is device 2 connected directly to R0? This connectivity makes use of both network domains, and I'm not confident that you actually *want* two network domains based on your question.

And finally, I would suggest a few things to remedy this:

1. Use R1 as a bridge, not as a router/gateway. This would make OpenWRT act as an L2 switch, placing all devices on a single L2/L3 domain (192.168.0.0/24) that the modem/router serves network services for (DHCP, DNS, and routing). This is the simplest solution, and I imagine *probably* what you're going for here. There would be no 192.168.1.0/24.
2. Configure R0 to act as a bridge, not as a router/gateway. This one is trickier, because it involves configuring this modem/router. There is probably a way to do that, though I'm not certain without you providing a model number. This way, the modem would be ONLY a modem and L2 bridge, and would only support a single device connecting to it - R1. R1 would get a public internet-facing address on its gateway NIC (provided via R0), and would be responsible for forming a NAT with that public IP and a private subnet (it could be anything you want, but let's keep it from possibly colliding if R0 gets reset and use 192.168.1.1/24). Device 2 would not connect to R0, but instead to R1. If you want to accomplish some kind of DMZ for device 2, you can do so via OpenWRT in R1.
3. Get a different modem. Depending on what kind of fabric you're using, this can be pretty trivial. Don't put up with an unruly device in your network that makes you jump through a bunch of hoops. It sounds like the hardware in it isn't great anyways. This is what I would do, in conjunction with option 2. If it's something like a cable modem, the surfboard models are good. I would avoid combination devices, and get JUST a modem that presents ethernet on a single RJ45 jack.

Comment: “Why is device 2 connected directly to R0?” The core question I have as well. What is the benefit of that for the end user?

Comment: The answer is simple: It has 4 Ethernet Ports and I do not want to add an additional switch to my setup. It is perfectly fine for me to use 0.0/24 for the whole network but I am struggling with the configuration. I can disable the DHCP Server from R0 and run it on R1. But which device would be the gateway to the internet and which one provides the DNS? And how do I configure the DHCP Server so the right information is distributed to the clients? I want to use the R1 DNS because of the integrated adblock plugin. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to go with your Option 1, configure R1 to do DNS and DHCP and still have support for Upnp via R0?

Comment: If you configure R1 to serve those services on its bridge IP, and turn those services on R0 off, then yes. If the L2/L3 domain is flat, feel free to have either network node serve these things in any mixture you want - but don't run overlapping services on both nodes unless they're configured to be clustered.